# VHDL Syntax error in user defined package RNG for genetic algorithm in line number 5

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl, genetic-algorithm, xilinx

```
Library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

Type arr is array (1 to mut_bits) of integer;

type chrom_matrix is array (1 to pop_size) of std_logic_vector(1 to n_comp);

type fitness_arr is array (1 to pop_size) of integer range 0 to 1000;

--type fitness_arr1 is array(1 to pop_size) of real;

type adj_matrix is array (1 to n_comp,1 to n_comp) of bit;


function evalfnc (signal chromosome: in std_logic_vector(1 to 8); signal cut_info:adj_matrix) return integer;

procedure randg (variable x,y,t:in integer range 0 to 1000; variable z: out integer);

procedure convert_bit(variable a:in integer;variable y:out std_logic_vector(8 downto 1));

end rng;

package body rng is

procedure randg (variable x,y,t:in integer range 0 to 1000; variable z: out integer) is

variable val, a:integer range 0 to 1000:= 0;

begin

if x>y then

a:= x-y;

else

a:= y-x;

end if;

if t > 3*a then

  val:= (t-a)/2;

  elsif t > a then

  val:= t-a;

    else

    val:= (x+y+t)/2;

    end if;

    z:= val;

    end randg;

    function evalfnc (signal chromosome: in std_logic_vector(1 to 8); signal cut_info:adj_matrix) return integer is

    variable fitness: integer range 0 to 500:= 0;

    variable cut_val: integer range 0 to 15:= 0;

    variable max_fit:integer range 0 to 360:=100;

    begin

     for i in 1 to n_comp loop

       for j in 1 to n_comp loop

        if cut_info(i,j)= ‘1’ then

                               cut_val:= cut_val +1;

             end if;

    end loop;

 end loop;

   fitness := max_fit - cut_val;

   return fitness;

   end evalfnc;


procedure convert_bit(variable a:in integer ; variable y:out std_logic_vector(8 downto 1)) is

variable no:std_logic_vector(8 downto 1):=”00000000”;

variable num: integer range 0 to 256;

begin

    num:= a;

if num <= 255 and num>= 128 then

no(8):=’1’;

num:=num - 128;

end if;

if num < 128 and num >= 64 then

     no(7):=’1’;

     num:=num - 64;

end if;

     if num < 64 and num >= 32 then

     no(6):=’1’;

     num:=num −32;

end if;

if num < 32 and num >= 16 then

     no(5):=’1’;

     num:=num - 16;

       end if;

        if num < 16 and num >= 8 then

       no(4):=’1’;

       num:=num - 8;

           end if;

           if num < 8 and num >= 4 then

        no(3):=’1’;

         num:=num - 4;

                end if;

                if num < 4 and num >= 2 then

           no(2):=’1’;

          num:=num - 2;

                end if;

                if num < 2 then

           no(1):=’1’;

           end if;

y:= no;

end convert_bit;

end rng;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Actually, your error is obvious, but had it not been, it would have been helpful to say what the error message actually was. It is also helpful to submit an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than zillions of lines of code. In assembling your MCVE, you'd probably have spotted your error. Also, had you indented your code more conventionally, you'd have spotted it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 5 should read `package rng is`.